# Technical e-commerce term for products which need to be bought together

Tags: e-commerce

I am looking for a e-commerce solution which can allow the following feature...

For example the user has to purchase a mobile phone it is must that they have to purchase a earphone with it. So, at the time of purchase of mobile phone the e-commerce solution should provide an option of selecting ear phones too...

Q. What is this feature called, I remember reading about this feature in some technical document but not able to remember the name of it. I am looking for this feature in Magento, PrestaShop & X-Cart.

Comment: @Carl, looks like it is not "optional extras"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. They are called

> Bundled Products